# Pyhton generated latex file throws UTF-8 error

Tags: python, latex

I am trying to write a python program to generate and compile a Lualatex file with German special characters (ä, ü, ß etc.).
Unfortunately, it throws me this error:

```
! String contains an invalid utf-8 sequence.
```

Here is my example code:

```
import subprocess
import shutil

txtFileRecipe = open(r"C:\Users\canna\OneDrive\Desktop\TestTest.tex", "w")
txtFileRecipe.write(
    ("\\documentclass[a5paper]{article}\n"
    "\\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}\n"
    "\\usepackage{fontspec}\n"
    "\\begin{document}\n"
    "Äpfelmüß\n"
    "\\end{document}\n")
)
txtFileRecipe.close()
subprocess.check_call(["LuaLatex", r"C:\Users\canna\OneDrive\Desktop\TestTest.tex"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try opening the file as binary an encoding it to UTF-8

```
with open(r"C:\Users\canna\OneDrive\Desktop\TestTest.tex", "wb") as txtFileRecipe:
    txtFileRecipe.write(
        ("\\documentclass[a5paper]{article}\n"
        "\\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}\n"
        "\\usepackage{fontspec}\n"
        "\\begin{document}\n"
        "Äpfelmüß\n"
        "\\end{document}\n"
        .encode('utf-8')) #explicit encoding as utf-8
    )
subprocess.check_call(["LuaLatex", r"C:\Users\canna\OneDrive\Desktop\TestTest.tex"])
```

(Switched to opening the file with context manager to follow good practices)